# Why do I get a compile error on Optional.map(byte[]::clone)?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, arrays, option-type

I can't definitely find a suitable answer for my problem here on SO.
Situation: at work I checked out an existing Java8 project. I use Eclipse Neon (4.6.0)

A class has this field:

```
private final byte[] stream;
```

The class constructor has this parameter:

```
byte[] stream
```

and it does this:

```
    this.stream = Optional.ofNullable(stream)
            .map(byte[]::clone)
            .orElse(ArrayUtils.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY);
```

Unfortunately, there is an error on the expression: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to byte[]` especially as the `.map(byte[]::clone)` part returns an `Optional<Object>` (according to Eclipse) and not a `Optional<byte[]>`.

As I'm the only one using Eclipse - the others use IntelliJ and they don't have the error - I'm left on my own with this.

What can/should I do (apart from casting as `byte[]` somewhere in the expression as suggested as a quick fix by Eclipse)?

Note: I recall having seen a similar *weird* compile error with Java 1.5 generics several years ago, but that was the other way round: it was OK for me using Eclipse, but the other guy I worked with used Netbeans and he had the compile error (after some search he found out it was a bug in the JDK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should report this as a bug in Eclipse since it compiles using the standard `javac` compiler and in other IDEs. Specifically it looks like Eclipse is missing the following from the Java Language Specification section on [Array Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The `public` `final` field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.
> - **The `public` method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`**.

Note that the return type of `clone` overriden in `byte[]` is in fact `byte[]`, not `Object`. It seems the Eclipse compiler is inferring the type as `Object`.

Comment: I submitted a bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498362

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. The existing support for array clone methods didn't work as intended for method references. This has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an Eclipse bug. As a work-around you may use lambda expression instead:

```
this.stream = Optional.ofNullable(stream)
        .map(b -> b.clone())
        .orElse(new byte[0]);
```

It works correctly.